# How do I get the python call stack from C#?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I am using IronPython to run python scripts inside of a C# application. The python script then can have different function calls and at some moment it makes a call to a C# function using an API. From within this called C# function I would like to be able to tell the call stack from the python side.

If I use System.Diagnostics.StackTrace I get the call stack for the IronPython interpreter which is running the python script, no the python script call stack itself.

Comment: Hi @AntonioLuna, did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, I did not. I had to use try/except at the python scripts themselves and log any exception into a logger handler which the .NET application had created. That way I had, at least, a shared logger between the .NET app and the python script which showed the python-side exceptions.
Once IronPython3 is ready I expect to give this a try again.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for coming back to answer!